# Hooking in C and windows

Tags: c, windows, hook

I'm looking for a quick guide to basic dll hooking in windows with C, but all the guides I can find are either not C, or not windows.

(The DLL is not part of windows, but a third party program)

I understand the principle, but I don't know how to go about it.

I have pre-existing source code in C++ that shows what I need to hook into, but I don't have any libraries for C, or know how to hook from scratch.

Comment: Hooking what? A library call? System events e.g. mouse and keyboard activity? Something else?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, but if by "hooking" you mean what I think you mean, it's a very fragile, backwards, hackish practice that you should not be doing. Hooking breaks very badly if multiple hooks are installed (and even moreso if they're later uninstalled) due to order issues. Why not instead post a question about the goal you're trying to achieve rather than asking how to duplicate a wrong solution from 1980s-era DOS TSRs?

Comment: What does the C++ code do? The Windows APIs related to hooking are going to be the same in C and C++. They're all C functions.

Comment: DLL hooking, not hooking a windows DLL, but a third party program. @CodyGray: I was thinking of Detours, I thought that was limited to C++ as the only examples I can find are in C++

Comment: Hmm, I haven't actually used Detours, but there's probably nothing in the code that couldn't be written from C. C++ just makes large/complex programs easier to write and understand. You could also just write a wrapper over Detours that can be consumed from C code. What's the motivation for writing all the code in C?

Comment: Educational. Besides, I tend not to work well with OOP. I think I'll create a codecave with `createremotethread` to avoid having to bundle a separate dll with the program.

Answer (score 0):

The detours license terms are quite restrictive.

If you merely want to hook certain functions of a DLL it is often cheaper to use a DLL-placement attack on the application whose DLL you want to hook. In order to do this, provide a DLL with the same set of exports and forward those that you don't care about and intercept the rest. Whether that's C or C++ doesn't really matter. This is often technically feasible even with a large number of exports but has its limitations with exported data and if you don't know or can't discern the calling convention used.

If you **must** use hooking there are numerous ways including to write a launcher and rewrite the prepopulated (by the loader) IAT to point to your code while the main thread of the launched application is still suspended (see the respective `CreateProcess` flag). Otherwise you are likely going to need at least a little assembly knowledge to get the jumps correct. There are plenty of liberally licensed disassembler engines out there that will allow you to calculate the proper offsets for patching (because you don't want to patch the middle of a multi-byte opcode, for example).

You may want to edit your question again to include what you wrote in the comments (keyword: "DLL hooking").

Comment: Replacing the DLL is not an option, it's pretty big and this would breach the TOS for the program (That's the whole point of hooking rather than just monitoring network packets) I don't suppose the [Win32 CodeHook](http://www.kbasm.com/codehook.html) library would be of any use?

Comment: Did I write "replace" anywhere? Please do a web search what a "DLL placement attack" (or "DLL hijack" if you will) is ;) ... in all likelihood you need not move any files out but rather your own file into a place that is checked first by the mechanisms in the loader and APIs auch as `LoadLibrary`. There are plenty of ready-to-use libraries out there but I can hardly judge which one suits your needs (license-wise and from the technological point). BTW: would have been really great if you would have added all the constraints that you bring now up one by one into the original (or edited) question

Answer (score 0):

loading DLLs by LoadLibrary()

This is well known bad practice.

You might want to look up "witch" or "hctiw", the infamous malware dev. there's a reason he's so infamous - he loaded DLLs with LoadLibrary(). try to refrain from bad practice like that.